# How to pass Joomla parameters to an iframe (wrapper) page?

Tags: php, joomla

I try to fetch my users information using the getUser() function with a php script located in a iframe (wrapper) of Joomla. It seems there is problem passing parameters to iframe code. The only way I can catch user informations is to insert the code into a basic article (which is not an iframe).

The var_dump($user); output shows :

```
object(JUser)#17 (23) { ["isRoot":protected]=> NULL ["id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["password"]=> NULL ["password_clear"]=> string(0) "" ["usertype"]=> NULL ["block"]=> NULL ["sendEmail"]=> int(0) ["registerDate"]=> NULL ["lastvisitDate"]=> NULL ["activation"]=> NULL ["params"]=> NULL ["groups"]=> array(0) { } ["guest"]=> int(1) ["_params":protected]=> object(JRegistry)#18 (1) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#19 (0) { } } ["_authGroups":protected]=> NULL ["_authLevels":protected]=> NULL ["_authActions":protected]=> NULL ["_errorMsg":protected]=> NULL ["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } ["aid"]=> int(0) }
```

Some idea of what is going wrong ?
Thank you,
Florent

```
<?php

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$user = JFactory::getUser();

echo "<p>Your name is {$user->name}, your email is {$user->email}, and your username is $user->username}</p>";
echo "<p>Your usertype is {$user->usertype} which has a group id of {$user->gid}.</p>";
//var_dump($user);
?>
```

Comment: I can see that the problem concern the iframe (or 'wrapper') content. The code works normaly when it is inside regular article (I use sourcerer). Is there any setting needed for external iframe to works correctly ?

Comment: After some investigation I understand that I need to add the following in my iframe $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, wchen you use a wrapper, the Joomla environment is unknown. So you need to embed this before using Joomla API. To do this, just copy and paste this code (or create a new PHP file and include it in your custom page) :

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ); 
define( 'DS','/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS. 'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require(JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries/joomla/factory.php');

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the page that includes the iframe doesn't "know" Joomla - it's a different environment!

If I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve, then you really should create an article in Joomla that displays the user information, but instead of getting the user-id from:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

you should send it as POST/GET parameter from the OUTER page (you can add some kind of auth-string if security matters to you). The article will read this POST/GET parameter and display the user's information respectively.

The OUTER page (the one that contains the iframe) should refresh the iframe and use, as a url, the same url that displays the article (make sure it has "public" permissions) but will also send the user-id as parameter, for example:

```
iframe src="http://<url to joomla>?id=articleId&userId=<user-id>
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you alfasin. I should have mentioned that the iframe is also the homepage and it is probably better to initialise the Joomla environnement in it, as Arnaud propose.