# JFactory getUser randomly not working in wrapper

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working with an old 1.5.26 Joomla installation. I developed a web application for the site, embedded it with the joomla wrapper and decided to use the joomla user management for the access (insert the sound of a head hitting the wall here).

I used a simple code:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname((dirname(__FILE__))));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');    
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');    
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$usuario= JFactory::getUser();
$idUsuario=$usuario->id;
$nombreUsuario=$usuario->name;

if ($idUsuario==0)
{
     echo "<p>Error: no tiene permiso</p>";
     die ();
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Hola, $nombreUsuario.</p>";
}
/* And the script goes on... */
```

The thing is, everything works perfectly. I tested it in several computers with several web browsers (even with an iPad) and it seems to work fine. I was happy... until I moved on to production and allowed real users to access it.

Total and complete disaster. Many users (a lot of them) are getting the "error" message, jFactory::getUser returns a 0 for them. I use their usernames and passwords to try it and it works fine. They try from their end and it doesn't.

This only happens when I embed the script within the wrapper. If I let the users access the web application through a direct link to the application directory, the problem vanishes.

Does anyone have the slightest idea of why this could happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is the same as in this question [How to pass Joomla parameters to an iframe (wrapper) page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268225/how-to-pass-joomla-parameters-to-an-iframe-wrapper-page) where the answer suggests to include this in your script:

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ); 
define( 'DS','/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS. 'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require(JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries/joomla/factory.php');

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
?>
```

and also in this (which is almost the same code as yours): [Getting user information within wrapper](http://forum.codejoomla.com/open-source/joomla/getting-user-information-within-wrapper-1518.html)

Comment: Adding the 'factory.php' line Didn't work. I'll have to try editing the wrapper template as suggested by your link. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../' ));  
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');


    $user = & JFactory::getUser();
```

This works for me everywhere. Just pay attention to the /../
If the file you're putting in the iframe is with a deeper level, you can add more /../ 's

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about this one. Thank you, but I managed to switch to Joomla 3.x a while ago so the problem disappeared.